# I need to get the sum of each element from a list

Tags: list, netlogo

I have a list like that:

```
[[0 1 2] [4 6 9] ... [-1 0 3]]
```

and  I need to get `[3 19 ... 2]`, I mean sum of first element, second and .... n - element.

I´m gonna really appreciate your help.

Update: I tried with that:

```
to sum-first-item
  let out []
  ask turtles[
    let sum-elem sum map first data-train
    set out lput sum-elem out
  ]
end
```

Comment: Are you really using Netlogo for this?  What code do you already have?

Comment: Actually, I try to simplify my issue. I get data from a csv and I save it into a turtle attribute. For example data-train = [[0 1 2] [4 6 9] ... [-1 0 3]], and I need to get some information for each elements from data-train like mean, sum and save it in another attribute like [3 9 ... 12]

But I don't get good results. Because it returns the sum of the first values ​​of each element.

I'm sorry if I'm not clear.

Comment: @TimRoberts What a comment? There is no good reason to think that the OP is using NetLogo in order to accomplish this task instead of using, I don't know, pen and paper. Obviously they have to perform this calculation as part of a model...

Comment: @Matteo -- There are at least two good reasons -- they tagged "netlogo" and the original question had "Netlogo" in the title.

Comment: `map sum [[0 1 2] [4 6 9] [-1 0 3]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each list's item (in your case: each inner list) can be accessed by using `item` ([see here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#item), but also know about `first` and `last`) or as the current element of `foreach` ([see here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#foreach)).

Here a bunch of ways with which you can accomplish your goal. First showing simply how to operate on each inner list, then showing how to directly build a list containing each inner list's sum:

```
to play-with-lists
  print "The original list:"
  let list-of-lists [[0 1 2] [4 6 9] [-1 0 3]]
  print list-of-lists
  
  print "Manually reporting sums:"
  print sum item 0 list-of-lists
  print sum item 1 list-of-lists
  print sum item 2 list-of-lists
  
  print "Building a list of sums with while loop using 'while':"
  let list-of-sums []
  let i 0
  while [i < length list-of-lists] [
    set list-of-sums lput (sum item i list-of-lists) (list-of-sums)
    set i i + 1
  ]
  print list-of-sums

  print "Building a list of sums with for loop using 'foreach':"
  set list-of-sums []
  foreach list-of-lists [
    inner-list ->
    set list-of-sums lput (sum inner-list) (list-of-sums)
  ]
  print list-of-sums
  
  print "Building a list of sums using 'map':"
  print map sum list-of-lists
end
```

Comment: @AdrianLara You're welcome. Please see the updated answer, where I also included how to do it with `map`. Map automatically reports a list of results as computed for each item, so it is probably the most straightforward method and probably easier than what you thought, judging from your attempt!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Matteo's version with `map sum the-list` is the simpler solution so I suggest sticking with that. Still, it is useful to get to know reduce for when you need to do more complex calculations than summing.

Netlogo offers a few very powerful primitives to work with lists. I see you already use `map`, which runs a reporter for each item of a list and reports the resulting list.
Another one of those is `reduce`, which combines all items from a list into a single value by applying a reporter to them in turn. I suggest reading up on reduce in the dictionary and playing around with it a bit since it is not immediately obvious how it works (https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reduce).

Combining these two gives you this elegant piece of code:

```
to try

  let the-list[[0 1 2] [4 6 9] [-1 0 3]]
  show map [ x -> reduce + x] the-list 
  ;observer: [3 19 2]
  
end
```

Comment: Correct! Using `map` was the easiest solution but for some reason I hadn't thought about it in the first place. I had edited my answer adding `map` while you were probably typing yours. However I see you are doing it differently using `reduce`. Probably worth just having `map sum the-list`?

Comment: @Matteo Oh right, I forgot that `reduce +` is pretty much the same as `sum`. I agree, in this case `map sum the-list` is the better and easier option. I'll edit my answer instead of deleting since I still find it useful to point out the existance of `reduce`.

Comment: Yes absolutely leave it here. Perhaps because of its left-to-right orientation, which looks quite specific, I rarely remember of considering `reduce`... so it is worth to have it reminded

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I have several solutions for my model.